# Evaluate a strange integral involving generalized hypergeometric function ${}_1F_2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, contour-integration, hypergeometric-function

$$
\small I=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-4x}
\left (x^{-2/3}\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^2\,_1F_2
\left ( \frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3},\frac43;x^2   \right )^2
-\frac{9}{4}x^{2/3}\Gamma\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )^2
 \,_1F_2
\left ( \frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},\frac53;x^2   \right )^2  \right )\text{d}x
=\frac{2\pi^2}{9} \left [ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
-3^{-5/3}\left ( \sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{3}+3} +\sqrt[3]{ 2\sqrt{3}-3 } \right )    \right ].
$$
It's very strange(and ugly). This a corollary from complex analysis. Inasmuch as I have never met squared $\,_pF_q$, I post this on the site. Since the value only contain $\pi^2$, it would be easier to do through real method.

- $I$ is connected to a type of contour integrals,
  $
  \small\int_{0}^{x}K_{1/3}(t)\text{d}t.
  $ And if we generally consider $\small\int_{0}^{x}K_{\nu}(t)\text{d}t$, more generalizations are detected.
- I roughly think we can link ${}_1F_2$ with ${}_3F_2$ by calculating such integrals and then we are able to find linear relations among several ${}_3F_2$. But that's likely to be an *imagination*.

---

*Question*: Can we verify $I$ in other ways, especially in real method?

Comment: do you mind posting the original proof from complex analysis?

Comment: I consider this kind of questions when I want to be superior than WA.

Comment: Please mention a source where the result is shown (even using methods of complex analysis), this makes sure that all tiny decorations in the formula are displayed correctly. At least, some potential answerers may check it. Also, one may extract some algebraic information from the result, may see which is the essence of the proof, may get related results, etc. - at any rate, each answer will invest much more effort.

Answer (score 4):

There is a mistake in the result provided by OP, the integral actually is:
$$\int_0^1 x^2 e^{-4x}\left(x^{-2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)^2 {_1F_2}\left(\frac13;\frac23,\frac43;x^2\right)^2-\frac{9x^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)^2}{4} {_1F_2}\left(\frac23;\frac43,\frac53;x^2\right)^2\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{2\pi^2}{9}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt 3+3}+\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt 3-3}}{3^{5/3}}\right)$$

**This only contains some progress**

We will start by bringing the integral to a human-readable form. First, we can notice that the inner squared hypergeometric terms are a product of integrals of [Airy functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html).
$$\operatorname{Ai}(t)=\frac{1}{3^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{_0F_1}\left(;\frac23;\frac{t^3}{9}\right)-\frac{t}{3^{1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}{_0F_1}\left(;\frac43;\frac{t^3}{9}\right)$$
$$\operatorname{Bi}(t)=\frac{1}{3^{1/6}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{_0F_1}\left(;\frac23;\frac{t^3}{9}\right)+\frac{t}{3^{-1/6}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}{_0F_1}\left(;\frac43;\frac{t^3}{9}\right)$$

Integrating those gives:

$$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3x}\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Ai}(t)dt=x^{-1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right) {_1F_2}\left(\frac13;\frac23,\frac43;x^2\right)-\frac{3x^{1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{2} {_1F_2}\left(\frac23;\frac43,\frac53;x^2\right)$$

$$\frac{2\pi}{3x}\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Bi}(t)dt=x^{-1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right) {_1F_2}\left(\frac13;\frac23,\frac43;x^2\right)+\frac{3x^{1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{2} {_1F_2}\left(\frac23;\frac43,\frac53;x^2\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow x^{-2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)^2 {_1F_2}\left(\frac13;\frac23,\frac43;x^2\right)^2-\frac{9x^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)^2}{4} {_1F_2}\left(\frac23;\frac43,\frac53;x^2\right)^2$$
$$=\frac{4\pi^2}{3\sqrt 3x^2}\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Ai}(t)dt\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Bi}(t)dt$$

So we can rewrite the original integral as:

$$I = \frac{4\pi^2}{3\sqrt 3}\int_0^\infty e^{-4x}\left(\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Ai}(t)dt\int_0^{\large (3x)^{2/3}}\operatorname{Bi}(t)dt\right)dx$$
$$\overset{(3x)^{2/3}\to x} = \frac{2\pi^2\sqrt 3}{9}\int_0^\infty \sqrt x e^{\large -4/3x^{3/2}}\left(\int_0^x \operatorname{Ai}(t)dt\int_0^x \operatorname{Bi}(t)dt\right)dx$$

---

The Airy functions can also be written as:
$$\operatorname{Ai}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \cos\left(ty+\frac{y^3}{3}\right)dy$$
$$\operatorname{Bi}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \left( \sin\left(ty+\frac{y^3}{3}\right)+\exp\left(ty-\frac{y^3}{3}\right)\right)dy$$

And their respective integrals can be found on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.10), however it wasn't much of a help for me going forward. But surely, finding a single integral representation for the product of the integrals of the Airy functions would be extremely helpful.

A better idea I think is to make use of [the connection formulas](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.2#v).
$$\operatorname{Ai}(t)\pm i\operatorname{Bi}(t)=-2e^{\mp 2i\pi/3}\operatorname{Ai}\left(e^{\mp 2i\pi/3}t\right)dt$$
$$\Rightarrow \operatorname{AB}_{\pm}(x) = \int_0^x \left(\operatorname{Ai}(t)\pm i\operatorname{Bi}(t)\right)dt=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(e^{\mp 2i\pi/3}xt+\frac{t^3}{3}\right)}{t}dt$$
And now, since $4iab = (a+ib)^2 - (a-ib)^2$ we can write:
$$4i\int_0^x\operatorname{Ai}(t)\int_0^x\operatorname{Bi}(t)=\operatorname{AB}_{+}^2(x)-\operatorname{AB}_{-}^2(x)$$

$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{4i}\frac{2\pi^2 \sqrt 3}{9} \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(x^{3/4} e^{-2/3 x^{3/2}} \operatorname{AB}_{+}(x)\right)^2-\left(x^{3/4} e^{-2/3 x^{3/2}} \operatorname{AB}_{-}(x)\right)^2}{x}dx$$
Going further, [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Properties) gives us:
$$I=\frac{1}{8\pi i}\frac{2\pi^2\sqrt 3}{9}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\left|\mathcal M \left(g_{+}(it)\right)\right|^2-\left|\mathcal M \left(g_{-}(it)\right)\right|^2\right)dt$$
$$g_{\pm}(x)=x^{3/4} e^{-2/3 x^{3/2}} \operatorname{AB}_{\pm}(x);\quad \mathcal M \left(f(x)\right)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1} f(x)dx$$

The [Mellin transform of the Airy function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.10#vi) is simple enough, however due to the exponential term I couldn't proceed further (even by expanding it into power series).

Also seeing such a squared function integrated over $\mathcal R$ usually reminds us of [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering), which uses Fourier's transform, therefore here it can be useful to make use of the [connection between the Mellin and Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Relationship_to_other_transforms). However I got lost here for now and I'm posting only to give some ideas.

Comment: Investigating the primitive function $F(x)$ of $K_{1/3}(x)$, then construct a function which decays to $0$ all through as $|z|$ approaching $\infty$. The simplest one is $e^x(F(x)-F(\infty))$.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory I don't understand if you're talking about something from my answer or if you are just giving more context. Note that all that's left is to show the following two results:

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt x e^{\large -4/3x^{3/2}}\int_{-\infty}^x \operatorname{Ai}(t)dt\int_{-\infty}^x  \operatorname{Bi}(t)dtdx=\frac13$$
$$\frac23\int_0^\infty \sqrt x e^{\large -4/3x^{3/2}}\int_{-\infty}^x  \operatorname{Bi}(t)dtdx=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt 3+3}+\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt 3-3}}{\sqrt 3 \cdot 3^{5/3}}$$
Do you have any ideas that doesn't use contour integration?